# IND-CPA for permutation based encryption

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

My encryption function is some permutation using a permutation key.
An input to the encryption function is encoding of my plain text where one plaintext is mapped to many encodings.
Can we prove semantic security of this encryption?
If so how? Can any one please help me out?
Note: Both Plaintext and its encoding are binary strings (0's and 1's)

Comment: Note:  plaintext and its encoding both are of binary strings

Comment: Whether or not such an encryption scheme is secure depends on the details of your instantiation that you omitted in your question.